# Node with curved, parallel lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to create a node style, which consists of a circle with two lines (curved inwards possibly) connecting `south west` with `south east` and `north west` with `north east`.

After a bit of research, I found a way that in principle should be the solution:

```
\tikzset{
Vh/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size=1cm, ultra thick, text = black, path picture={%
        \draw (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
              (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.south west)
              (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
      ;}}
```

However, for some reason, this only produces the diagonal lines. Neither vertical nor horizontal lines work with this solution. But why? Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong? Is there a nicer solution?

Comment: Straight lines because you are using `--`. You need to use `bend`

Comment: Of course, thats the second step. However, with this code only two of the three (streight) lines show up! Curving the third one will be easier after it is showing up.

Comment: north east to north west is the edge and the circle node inscribes that bounding box hence invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
Vh/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size=1cm, ultra thick, text = black, path picture={%
        \draw (path picture bounding box.south east) to[bend right] (path picture bounding box.south west)
              (path picture bounding box.north east) to[bend left] (path picture bounding box.north west)
      ;}}
      }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[Vh] {here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The changed lines are

```
\draw (path picture bounding box.south east) to[bend right] (path picture bounding box.south west)
                  (path picture bounding box.north east) to[bend left] (path picture bounding box.north west)
```

where `to[bend left/right]` has been used.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Still not sure why the version I gave only produces diagonal lines but yours is working.

Comment: Pay attention to `--`. It has been replaced with `to[bend right]`. As I said in my comment in your question. If this solves your problem, you should accept it an answer. More info, read the manual page 48 `3.10 Connecting Nodes`.

Comment: @Hagadol Eventhough your node is circular, it's bounding box is a square with the circle inscribed, so `(path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)` is a straight line on the edge of the square so it's "invisible" for the circular inscribed node.